# Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain]

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

I'm trying to run a pig script by triggering it through oozie. Here is the workflow.xml, job.properties and error message. Please help me to solve the issue. I am using BigInsight VM to run this.

```
workflow.xml

    <workflow-app name="PigApp" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="PigAction"/>
<action name="PigAction">
<pig>
<job-tracker>${jobtracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${namenode}</name-node>

<prepare></prepare>

<configuration>
<property>
<name>oozie.action.external.stats.write</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.pig</name>
<value>pig</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx2048m -Xms1000m -Xmn100m</value>
</property>

</configuration>



</pig>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
<message>Error message[${wf:errorMessage()}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>



Job.properties

    #JobTracker and NodeName
jobtracker=bivm:9001
namenode=bivm:9000

#HDFS path where you need to copy workflow.xml and lib/*.jar to

oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://bivm:9000/user/biadmin/oozieWF/
oozie.libpath=hdfs://bivm:9000/user/biadmin/oozieWF/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.action.sharelib.for.pig=pig

wf_path=hdfs://bivm:9000/user/biadmin/oozieWF/

#one of the values from Hadoop mapred.queue.names
queueName=default

    enter code here

Error Message: 

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], main() threw exception, jline.ConsoleReaderInputStream
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline.ConsoleReaderInputStream
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:283)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:219)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:366)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.ConsoleReaderInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:942)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:851)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:827)
    ... 18 more
```

If it is problem related to pig jar then specify the version on link to download. I'm using pig 0.12.0 jar.

Comment: Hi... Is there anyone who can help on this,

Comment: Did you leave out the <script> in the pig action intentionally? Otherwise error seems to indicate a missing jar.

Comment: Whenever I'm putting the <script > after configuration and saving it. It is just not saving the script part. This may be a problem of BigInsight VM.